# A method that run authomatically when instaciate a class with a duplicate variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

`earth` is a class standing for some countries.  When I instantiate a country, `total_population` increases by `1` person and the population of that country starts at `1`. We can add\sub `1` to\from total-poulation and country-population using `burn()` or `die()` methods.

```
>>> class earth:
    population=0

    def __init__(self):
        self.population=1
        earth.population+=1
        print("Total:"+str(earth.population),"This Country:"+str(self.population))

    def __del__(self):
        earth.population -= self.population
        self.population = 1
        print("Total:"+str(earth.population),"This Country:"+str(self.population))

    def burn(self):
        self.population+=1
        earth.population+=1
        print("Total:"+str(earth.population),"This Country:"+str(self.population))

    def die(self):
        self.population-=1
        print("Total:"+str(earth.population),"This Country:"+str(self.population))
        earth.population+=1


>>> Amerca=earth()
('Total:1', 'This Country:1')

>>> Amerca=earth()
('Total:2', 'This Country:1')
('Total:1', 'This Country:1')
```

Questions:

Why when I instantiate the class with a name that I used before, I have two line output? does the `__init__` and `__del__` both runs? How I can make one of the runs before another?  I mean which one run before another?  can I change the sequence?

As I see , in this case when I instantiate a name that I used before, first `__init__` run and then `__del__` runs! right? if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first `__init__` for the second instance is being called, to create it. Then, because the first instance is no longer referred to by any variable it is being deleted. It is being deleted because after the last variable which was pointing to it is rebound to something else it is impossible to reach it anymore, hence it can be safely deleted.

It really unclear what are you trying to achieve, and why do you do it in such a strange way, but you can influence the order in which they're being run like this:

```
x = earth()
('Total:1', 'This Country:1')    # __init__ called
x = None
('Total:0', 'This Country:1')    # __del__ called as first instance is no longer used
x = earth()
('Total:1', 'This Country:1')    # __init__ called again for the second instance
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> Called when the instance is about to be destroyed. This is also called a destructor. If a base class has a **del**() method, the derived class’s **del**() method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper deletion of the base class part of the instance. Note that it is possible (though not recommended!) for the **del**() method to postpone destruction of the instance by creating a new reference to it. It may then be called at a later time when this new reference is deleted. It is not guaranteed that **del**() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

Comment: I don't have any control on the end-user that instaciate the class. So how I can change the code in a way that it works fine? I mean if the end user just enter a name for the contry and click on a button to instanciate, in which way I must change the code to have only one line output always?

Comment: @User1-St To have just one line of output always just don't use `__del__`/don't print in `__del__`. It's really unclear what do you want to achieve. Refer to: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This is my question : I want method `__del__` to print the populations when the variable deleted using `del` command,and don't print populations when it rebound to something else! Is this possible? (making different between `del` and rebounding!)

Comment: @User1-St No it's not possible (refer to the documentation I've linked to). You could just add your own method `deletePopulation` which will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), `a = b` means "evaluate b", which in this case calls **init**, and then "bind the result to 'a'".  The second step necessarily unbinds 'a' from anything else.  If, as in this case, 'a' was the only reference to the previous object, then `__del__`, if present, is called.

Some other notes: 'instantiate' is spelled this way.  In `__del__`, self.population should becomes 0, not 1, or perhaps not be modified or printed.  Since burning can kill, 'burn' appears to be a misspelling of 'born'.  In `die`, the total population should decrease, not increase, and before being printed.

Comment: Thank you Dear Trry :) (Specially for _Some other notes_) ;)